# Redirect REST API response to UI/Browser NodeJs/Express/Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

Not able to send response of a REST api callout to browser page using NodeJs server with `Express` and `Request` module.

I understand that due to asynchronous nature of callback method, response of api callout cannot be returned in typical style.

I have tried res.send method, but it gives error `res.send` is not a function.

Below is sample piece of that I have tried.

```
        const options = {
            url: endPoint,
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8'
            }
        };
        request(options, (err, res, body) => {
            if (err) { return console.log(err); }
            //want to send this body to the page.
            console.log(JSON.stringify(body));
            res.send(body);
        });
```

It gives this error message,

```
res.send(body);
TypeError: res.send is not a function
at Request.request [as _callback]
```

Comment: can you post the code where us defined the `request`

Comment: Looks like you using requestjs. The res is response of resquestjs, not route handler (req, res, next)

Comment: @TRomesh/vun I am using this module of nodeJs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Comment: You are using request which makes calls to external url and get data which is in res. Now you have to use expreee and nodejs mothod to send those data back to browser page. **res** in request package is just response of call. Store it send via express or node call

Comment: Thanks Vipul. Can you guide me to post/url where I can see the sample code of how to do it?

Comment: Can someone guide me to the right direction, please? :) I have tried few things by myself but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Figured the issue. 
First problem was as @vipul pointed above. **res** was response of callout and not instance of global HttpResponse object, so send method was not available on that object. I changed the method,

```
    request(options, (err, response, body) => {
        if (err) { return console.log(err); }
        //want to send this body to the page.
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.body));
        // using the HttpResponse in global context.
        this.res.send(JSON.parse(body));
    });
```

Then I faced below error,

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client]
```

Problem was while making the callout, I was returning the response right after callout method.

```
  .get('/authorize', (req, res) => {
      console.log('Authorize Hit! '+req.query.code);
      try {
          //TODO: Need to utilize state to the current flow in action.
          let flowDetails = flow.flowMap.get('wsf');
          if(flowDetails) {
            //this method makes REST API call
            flowDetails.refreshToken(req, res);
            //this line was the problem!! Removed it to fix the error.
            res.send('Refresh Token Completed!');
          }
      } catch (error) {
          (Object.keys(error).length === 0)?res.send(error.message):res.send(error);
      }
  })
```

But due to asynchronous nature of callback function, by the time callout response was received, actual request/response was already returned and request was completed. So removed the res.send right after callout to fix the issue.

Hopefully it will be helpful for others as well :)